# Spring bean references across multiple thread

Tags: java, multithreading, spring, dependency-injection

I have come across a scenario as below:

MyBean - Defined in XML Configuration.

I need to inject MyBean into multiple threads. 
But my requirements is:
1) The reference retrieved in two different threads should be different
2) But I should get the same reference irrespective how many times I retrieve bean from single thread.

Eg :

```
Thread1 {

    run() {
        MyBean obj1 = ctx.getBean("MyBean");
        ......
        ......
        MyBean obj2 = ctx.getBean("MyBean");
    }
}

Thread2 {

    run(){
        MyBean obj3 = ctx.getBean("MyBean");
    }
}
```

So Basically `obj1 == obj2` but `obj1 != obj3`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the custom scope named `SimpleThreadScope`.

From the `Spring` documentation :

> As of `Spring 3.0`, a thread scope is available, but is not registered
>   by default. For more information, see the documentation for
>   [SimpleThreadScope](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/support/SimpleThreadScope.html). For instructions on how to register this or
>   any other custom scope, see Section [3.5.5.2, “Using a custom
>   scope”](http://static.springsource.org/autorepo/docs/spring/3.0.0.RC1/spring-framework-reference/html/ch03s05.html#beans-factory-scopes-custom-using).

Here an example of how to register the SimpleThreadScope scope :

```
Scope threadScope = new SimpleThreadScope();
beanFactory.registerScope("thread", threadScope);
```

Then, you'll be able to use it in your bean's definition  :

```
<bean id="foo" class="foo.Bar" scope="thread">
```

You can also do the Scope registration declaratively :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd">

    <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.CustomScopeConfigurer">
        <property name="scopes">
            <map>
                <entry key="thread">
                    <bean class="org.springframework.context.support.SimpleThreadScope"/>
                </entry>
            </map>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="foo" class="foo.Bar" scope="thread">
        <property name="name" value="bar"/>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Answer (score 2):

What you require is a new **Thread Local custom scope**. You can either implement your own or [use the one here](http://www.springbyexample.org/examples/custom-thread-scope-module.html).

> The Custom Thread Scope module is a custom scope implementation for
>   providing thread scoped beans. Every request for a bean will return
>   the same instance for the same thread.